# Why can't I extract the other pages of the same website using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote this code to extract multiple pages of data from this site (base URL - "https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/fiction").

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page = 1
book_title = []

while page != 5:
      url = 'https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/fiction?page={page}'
      response = requests.get(url)
      page_content = response.text
      doc = BeautifulSoup(page_content, 'html.parser')

      a_tags = doc.find_all('a', {'class': 'bookTitle'})
      for tag in a_tags:
        book_title.append(tag.text)

      page = page + 1
```

But it's only showing the first 50 books' data. How can I extract all fiction books' names extracting all pages using beautifulsoup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  make the pagination from fiction category of the books from your base base url, you need to input the `fiction` keyword in search box and click on search button then you will get this url :https://www.goodreads.com/search?q=fiction&qid=ydDLZMCwDJ and from here you have to collect data and to make the next pages.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

book_title = []

url = 'https://www.goodreads.com/search?page={page}&q=fiction&qid=ydDLZMCwDJ&tab=books'
for page in range(1,11):
    response = requests.get(url.format(page=page))
    page_content = response.text
    doc = BeautifulSoup(page_content, 'html.parser')

    a_tags = doc.find_all('a', {'class': 'bookTitle'})
    for tag in a_tags:
        book_title.append(tag.get_text(strip=True))

   
df = pd.DataFrame(book_title,columns=['Title'])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                 Title
0     Trigger Warning: Short Fictions and Disturbances
1    You Are Not So Smart: Why You Have Too Many Fr...
2       Smoke and Mirrors: Short Fiction and Illusions
3           Fragile Things: Short Fictions and Wonders
4                                   Collected Fictions
..                                                 ...
195  The Science Fiction Hall of Fame, Volume One, ...
196  The Art of Fiction: Notes on Craft for Young W...
197  Invisible Planets: Contemporary Chinese Scienc...
198                                  How Fiction Works
199  Monster, She Wrote: The Women Who Pioneered Ho...

[200 rows x 1 columns]
```